# Partition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ Space with $x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on a solution to exercise 11.4 b) in Daepp and Gorkin's Reading, Writing and Proving. The question is as follows:

For each $r \in \mathbb{R}$, let $A_r = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2\}$. Is this collection $\mathbf{A}$ of sets $A_r$ a partition of $X = \mathbb{R}^3$? If so give a geometric description of the partitioning sets and describe the equivalence relation implied by this partition.

I have the first part figured out and have concluded that it is a partitioning set. Each indexed set Ar is a sphere with radius r and so we can essentially "inflate" that sphere to infinite size among the R3 space. However, I am unsure how to give a 'geometric interpretation' and describe the equivalence relation. Any help would be really great!!

Thank you.

Comment: The geometric description is exactly as you said, namely dividing $\mathbb{R}^3$ into spheres with different radii. For the equivalence relation we say two points are equivalent if they lie in the same partition, how can you describe this equivalence using the term $A_r$ or "spheres", for example?

Comment: Would the points (x,y,z) corresponding to any specific radius just be related because they would comprise some specific vector coordinate/ ray from the origin? In this case, any two points ($x_1, y_1, z_1)$ ~ $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ simply as an extension of a particular ray which defines the radius? I am having trouble figuring out a way to express this mathematically using the definition of $A_r$ if this is in fact the case...

Comment: So any partition of a space/set/whatever defines an equivalence relation where two points/elements are equivalent iff they live in the same partition. In our case the partitions are the spheres $A_r$ of radius $r$. So $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2,y_3)$ are equivalent iff they lie on the same sphere iff $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = y_1^2 + y_2^2 + y_3^2.$

Comment: Sorry, where are you getting and $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3) and x = (y_1, y_2, y_3)$ from? And why are there no z values?

Comment: hmm if you prefer I can write $x = (x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $y = (x_2,y_2,z_2)$, and now $x$ and $y$ are equivalent iff $x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2 = x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2$.

Comment: Just to check, does the question specify $r \in \mathbb{R}$ (instead of $r\in\mathbb{R}^3$)? Separately, is there a condition such as $0 \leq r$ or $0 < r$? These details affect the answer.

Comment: So, the question says for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and then it defines the set  as it is defined above in the original question. There are no additional conditions. Would this affect anything??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r\in\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$, the set $A_r$ is exactly a sphere of radius $r$, as you say. Therefore, the collection of such $A_r$ for $r\geq 0$ forms a partition of $\mathbb R^3$, since each point $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$ belongs to exactly one such $A_r$. The geometric interpretation is just the fact that each $A_r$ is a sphere and $r$ is the distance of each point to the origin. The equivalence relation induced by this partition is that two points $\mathbf{r}_1\sim \mathbf{r}_2$ if and only if they have the same length $r_1=r_2$.

Note that for negative $r$, the way the question is written implies that $A_r=A_{-r}$ so the collection of sets $\{A_r\}$ is still the same as if we had just taken $r\geq 0$. So in either case we do in fact have a partition.